# Should there be a generic `paper-crafts` tag to cover all paper crafts like origami, kirigami, papercutting?

Tags: discussion

My Reason: people interested in paper crafts should find these questions under 1 umbrella. It will be helpful for users to find ***"what all is there, and what all can be done"*** w.r.t (in this case) paper.

The tag word is `paper-crafts`.

Someone suggested removing `paper` tag from my question. I thought `paper-crafts` might be a better tag and non ambiguous also.

I think this paper-craft tag involves word paper, so a special paper tag won't be necessary in these questions.

I suggest instead of paper tag with these questions,  we can have a paper-craft tag.

Also I suggest the paper-craft tag to be the parent tag attached to every question dealing with any kind of paper crafts.

Should there be a generic `paper-crafts` tag to cover  all paper crafts like origami,  kirigami,  papercutting?

Clarification : I am not suggesting in any way that all other tags be removed. All I am suggesting is that along with the tag origami, there should be a paper-craft tag also for the same question.

Comment: Do you mean **in addition** or **instead of**? Also, Paper craft is two words, so the tag would need to be [tag:paper-crafts].

Comment: Are you suggesting removing the tags in favour of the more specific ones or including a parent tag in those questions to group them together? My answer would be different depending which you meant.

Comment: Your edit doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Catija I think he means it to be __in addition to__ based on _Also I suggest the paper-craft tag to be the parent tag attached to every question dealing with any kind of paper crafts._

Comment: @Matt There's no such thing as a "parent tag". All tags are the same. Remember that questions are limited to five tags, so going too crazy with making non-realized "parent tags" can lead to issues with consistency.

Comment: @Matt no, I was thinking instead of . Because  word paper-craft includes paper.  Paper tag can be used in addition of this tag for the questions about choosing paper, as catija  said.  Call me she.

Comment: @Catija by parent tag, I meant a tag which always be there for all paper crafts questions. Like there is c++ tag on so.

Comment: On WW we have a tag for [power-tools] and it is commonly associated with something like a [table-saw]. but there are general [power-tool] questions that are not specific to [table-saw]s. Could that be the case here?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a type of craft *called* paper crafting, which encompasses many types of paper-based crafts. It's also called [paper modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_model). Models can be extremely complex and detailed, form abstract shapes (such as fractals!), or be more stylized (and even kid-friendly).

So, I think [paper-craft](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-craft) should be refer to that specific type of art.

Here are a couple examples.

[image]

[image]

---

As far as the scenarios mentioned in the OP, I think that the existing [tool-selection](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-selection) and [papercutting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papercutting) work pretty well. The specific example is for papercutting, not paper crafts in general, and about finding the correct tool.

It's important to realize that [papercutting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/papercutting) refers to a specific type of paper craft, and not the act of cutting paper itself. So, it already encompasses everything necessary for that question! This will be more clear as tag wikis get up and running.

Comment: So, can you suggest a better parent  tag which will encompass all paper crafts?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius To be honest, not at this moment. I'll think about it more, and may delete or update this answer based on what I come up with. I don't think one is really necessary, even though other fields such as `painting` may already have such a term.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Perhaps you could provide a case where an all-encompassing tag would be useful? In this case, paper-based art have pretty distinct subtypes, even "kids crafts". When would a user need to see *all* of these types, which vary wildy in skillsets, all in one go?

Comment: My only reason for a parent tag for all similar crafts is that it will be helpful for users to know "what all is there, and what all can be done" w.r.t (in this case) paper.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me. It's basically a tag that is so generic that it adds little to no value to the question. The type of paper craft is useful, such as origami, because if I'm specifically interested in origami, I don't have to wade through less relevant questions to get to it.

In a similar vein, tags like [painting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/painting) would have little value because watercolor isn't oil, etc. I think we want to avoid lumping similar arts and crafts together on the basis of a superficial similarity.

Comment: I agree that tags like painting generally won't be specific enough to be helpful.