# Can we make a papercraft tag? (and possibly delete the paper-crafts tag?)

Tags: discussion, tags

It sounds like we've kind of [decided that the [paper-craft] tag isn't particularly useful](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/should-there-be-a-generic-paper-crafts-tag-to-cover-all-paper-crafts-like-orig) and more of a meta tag.

And in the meantime, there's actually [a craft **called** papercraft](http://www.creativecloseup.com/20-beautiful-highly-detailed-papercraft-models)--cutting and gluing paper into 3D models.

It's in very wide use in Japan, and you can find a bunch of corporate sites that have print-cut-fold-glue templates out there.

- [Canon's papercraft website](http://cp.c-ij.com/en/categories/CAT-ST01-0071/top.html)
- [Yamaha's papercraft site](http://global.yamaha-motor.com/showroom/papercraft/)

When I tried to edit the tags on [a question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/418) to replace [paper-crafts] with [papercraft], I got the error message:

> You are attempting to create the tag [papercraft]; however the tag [paper-crafts] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

So. I'm raising it on meta. :D

Addendum:

My only problem is if a papercraft question comes up, the [papercraft**s**] tag still gets in the way. **Can we at least edit it so it's not plural?**  Craft tags are singular. It's not origamis, watercolors, bookbindings, knittings, or paintings.

Comment: We should wait to see what the community believes the [tag:paper-crafts] tag is. If many people are asking about this, then we should create the [tag:papercraft] tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'd vote no.

[We discussed this before](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/90/24), to some extent.

Papercraft and paper craft can be used interchangeably.

The tag wiki should be updated to reflect that it's for that specific type of craft.

However, I would suggest we add a [paper-model](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-model), and once users have enough reputation we can [paper-craft](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paper-craft) as a synonym. That should help guide proper usage.

Comment: Definitely agree on the tag wiki being updated. OTOH, if I type "paper model" into Google, I get about 400k hits. I punch in "paper craft", and I get 9.8M, suggesting to my simple mind that "paper craft"/papercraft is wider spread in usage. And that possibly paper-model and card-model should be the synonyms to papercraft.

Comment: @inkista It may get broader use because it's *also* used as a generic, but we're using it as a specific, so I'd rather the specific be the main term. If you type "paper craft" into the tag search, it'll suggest tag model and the wiki excerpt would start "For paper crafts..." or something similar. I *think* that would do it.

Comment: Good thoughts. I'm glad I brought this up.